# Why does zip return tuples?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm wondering why `zip()` was designed to return tuples and not lists for instance. Is it something that has to do with performance or mutability? Or is it something else?

Comment: Good question. Maybe it's just arbitrary?

Comment: I am not sure, but tuples are immutable whereas lists aren't.

Comment: My best hypothesis until now is that it might have something to do with the "in tuples, structure has meaning" thing, so in this case the position in tuples is semantically linked to the iterables being zipped. So for example index 1 in every tuple semantically 'points' to the second iterable which was processed by `zip()`.

Comment: Tuples also have a constant size and can be implemented more memory efficiently I would imagine

Comment: Also, Lists are typically used to contain elements of the same type. I imagine that `zip()` might return Tuples to cover the case where the items being zipped were of different types, and thus would be better suited in a Tuple.

Answer (score 5):

In the fact is that the zip function is designed to :

> Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences. (Source: the docstring of zip function)

From this with given arguments you only get one possible result which can't be affected by something else than input that you give. So if the result was list you can modify it and the result will no more be the one expected. The tuples are the solution because they are immutable and you can't affect the result.